# Adding extra "frames" in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I've just started using Pygame, and so far all my programs run like this pseudocode:

```
initialize game
while true:
    for each event:
        if event is close button:
            close()
        elif event is mouse button down:
            event_handler()

    logic()
    draw()
    update_display()
```

And this works fine for one "frame". However, what if I wanted a title screen (with, say, a click to begin), a main game (with the normal event handling), and a game over screen (with a key press to begin). I decided to implement it like this:

```
initialize game
frame = 0
while true:
    for each event:
        if event is close button:
            close()

        if frame == 0:
            if event is mouse button down:
                frame = 1

        elif frame == 1:
            if event is mouse button down:
                event_handler()

        elif frame == 2:
            if event is key button down:
                frame = 0

    if frame == 0:
        frame_zero_logic()
        frame_zero_draw()
    elif frame == 1:
        frame_one_logic()
        frame_one_draw()
    elif frame == 2:
        frame_two_logic()
        frame_two_draw()

    update_display()
```

However, I feel that is not the best implementation. What is the preferred way of implementing "multiple frames" in Pygame?

Answer (score 1):

For the lower part, I suggest you just say

```
frame.logic()
frame.draw()
```

and make sure your frame object provides the `logic` and `draw` methods.

As for the upper part, where you determine what your current `frame` actually is, it's a little trickier. I would probably set a boolean flag `is_finished` on each frame, allowing your loop to determine whether it can proceed to the subsequent frame. So I'd replace the code

```
if frame == 0:
    if event is mouse button down:
        frame = 1
    elif frame == 1:
        if event is mouse button down:
            event_handler()
    elif frame == 2:
        if event is key button down:
            frame = 0
```

by sth like

```
if frame.is_finished:
    frame = successor(frame)
```

Then you'd have to find a sensible way to determine each frame's successor. This should happen outside of your frames' implementation, so that the frame does not need to know its successor.

As for the mouse/key events: I'd pass them into the current frame objects to handle them. The object will possibly set its `is_finished` flag to `True` after processing them.